# Recursion tree for the problem Generate Subsets

Tags: recursion, subset, computer-science, diagram

I am learning about recursion, and I am stuck on the problem of generating all subsets of a string. I have written the code, but I am not sure how to create a tree diagram for it.
I understand the idea of the code, but I am not sure how to represent the recursive calls in a tree diagram. I am looking for some resources or a diagram that can help me with this problem.

```
void subset(string str, string curr, int i=0)
{
    if(i==str.length())
  {
    cout<<curr<<" ";
    return;
  }

  subset(str, curr, i+1);
  subset(str, curr+str[i], i+1);

}
```

Comment: *"the following code"*: ...is missing. Asking us to suggest resources is off topic here.